# How to open second video streaming on the same program opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video

How can I open second video streaming on the same program with the same camera.
I want record a video, stop these and do some think with movie, after these I want record new video on the same camera without stopping the program. Is it possible? When I use function to streaming and stop this, all works correct if I want use this function second time I have error:

> VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by
>   OpenCV
>
> VIDIOC_G_FMT: Invalid file descriptor
>
> VIDIOC_G_FMT: Invalid file descriptor
>
> VIDIOC_STREAMON: Invalid file descriptor

I write on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in c++ and use OpenCV 3.0.0

This is function to video streaming

```
bool videoStream(){

    VideoCapture stream1(0);

    if (!stream1.isOpened()) { 
        cout << "cannot open camera";
        exit(-1);
        return false;
    }

    double dWidth = stream1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    double dHeight = stream1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

    namedWindow("cam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    cvStartWindowThread();
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler); //catch Ctrl+C
    int n = 0;
    char filename[200];

    //unconditional loop
    while (true) {
        Mat frame;
        bool bSuccess = stream1.read(frame);

        if (!bSuccess) {
            cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
            break;
            destroyWindow("cam");
            return false;
        }


        if(!frame.empty()){
            imshow("cam", frame);
        }

        char key = (char)waitKey(30); 
        switch (key) {
            case 'q':
            case 'Q':
            case 27: return false;
            case ' ': //Save an image
                sprintf(filename,"filename%.3d.jpg",n++);
                imwrite(filename,frame);
                cout << "Saved " << filename << endl;
                if(n==10){
                    destroyWindow("cam");
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            default: break;
        }
        if(flag==1){
            flag=0;
            destroyWindow("cam");
            return false;
        }
    }
    destroyWindow("cam");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try calling stream1.release() if the stream is successfully opened (make sure you call it appropriately for every case in your use-case statement)

Comment: I think, the problem would be, because streaming isn't close and I can't open new streaming on the same camera. So, how can I close streaming without stop main program?

Comment: Just call the release method of your stream object (stream1.release())

Comment: It doesn't work, but I change program to not open videocapture second time.